# Join function with broken for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

Why does this work:

```
"".join(str(i) for i in range(10))
```

and this does not?

```
for i in range(10):
...     "".join(str(i))
```

I want the the second one to output the same string of 1-9 digits.
I am new to python.

Comment: you need an iterable to join it.. Just print the numbers without spaces or newline to get your output in the second case. No need for `join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.join` expects an iterable, which you're providing in both cases.

In the first case, the generator comprehension provides the digits to the same `join` function and you get your expected result.

In the second case, `join` iterates on the characters of a digit as string, and rebuilds it identical (so `join` is useless here):

`"".join(str(i))` is the same as `str(i)`

And since you're supposedly printing those expressions you end up adding a newline in between each digit. In your loop you would need `print(i,end="")` (python 3)

As a side note

```
"".join([str(i) for i in range(10)])
```

is slightly more performant than just

```
"".join(str(i) for i in range(10))
```

because `join` needs to build a list anyway to allocate the destination string. Passing a list directly speeds up the process.

Comment: Do you mean in the second case I am inherently inserting a new-line character between each character for the numbers?

Thanks for the side not though. As I said, I am new to Python